# Connect multiple Android smartphones to tablet

Tags: android, networking, client-server

I am trying to develop an android client-server to implement games like this:

1. you have got a tablet running as a server and waiting for clients to join
2. each client is a smartphone and starts an app, which shows a gamepad view when the connection is established.
3. Sending inputs from smartphone to the tablet and update() und the tablet figure movements etc.

My question is: what kind of communication is practicable? I would prefer a TCP connection with sockets but is there a more simple way?

Comment: read [it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's practical, and no, there isn't a simpler way. NFC won't do what you want, and bluetooth is a pain to configure for this sort of thing. You can make discovery easy by using [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) or, on older Android versions, [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/).